# Определить дату через определенное кол-во дней?

Tags: php

Как определить какая дата будет через 15 дней? Сегодняшнюю дату вывожу так:

```
echo date("d-m-Y");
```

Как определить какая дата будет через 15 дней?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `strtotime()`, например:

```
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime('15 days'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = (new DateTime('+15 Day'))->format("d.m.Y");
```

date и strtotime сейчас лучше не использовать скоро 2038. (Если версия php позволяет конечно)

Comment: Автор дело знает! Верьте ему и, по возможности, повинуйтесь!

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно не просто вывести дату, лучше использовать Datetime

```
$date = new DateTime(); //текущее время
$date->add(new DateInterval('P15D'));
echo $date->format("d-m-Y");
```